# OpenSSL keyUsage as CA

Tags: openssl, certificate, ca

How could I set the keyUsage of new a certificate signed by my CA that will have the same policies?

I tried to generate a certificate by running the command below:

```
openssl ca \
  -policy policy_anything \
  -cert ca.cer \
  -in cerreq.csr \
  -keyfile ca.key \
  -days 365 \
  -out cer.cer
```

Is there command parameter that should I include to set the keyUsage for the certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `-extenstions v3_ca`
This extenstion will add `basicConstraints = CA:true`, which means that you will be able to sign certificates with this certificate.